# Is this meaning of 'ward' part of proper English?

Tags: word-meaning

I was looking at dictionary meanings of the word 'ward'. What I expected (from encountering the word in RPG games) a meaning of '*magical shield or protective enchantment*' or similar, but I didn't find any. Closest I found was '*part of the mechanism that prevents the wrong key from opening a lock*'.

Is there a similar meaning of 'ward' in proper English?

Edit: I am referring to the lone word, as a noun.

Answer (score 4):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ward) definition 8:

> a means of protection

Does that fit what you are asking? I mean obviously this is not very specific. Also there is the phrasal verb *to ward off*, which means

> Prevent from harming or affecting one

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ward)

So you can see the two are connected. *Ward* is a very old word in English. See [etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ward) for its original meanings.

RPG games sometimes use older words such as *ward* to hearken back to the good old days of fighting and wenching. The *magical* part can come from *warding something off*, such as a vampire, by 'magical powers' inherent in garlic, mirrors, the cross  etc. and an RPG could expand on that.

Comment: 'a means of protection' would indeed be very general; and I am not referring to an agent noun. More like a thing, that's lifeless. Like a wall or shield.

Comment: Maybe the word 'ward' meaning a borne child, stemmed from the second(verb) meaning, as the mother guards her young after birth till they are mature enough to be on their own.

Comment: I think GoDucks' definition is exactly the correct one.  For example, an amulet *to ward off the evil eye* would be a *means of protection against the evil eye*.  I'm not sure why you think "means of protection" is an agent noun, or why it would not be a lifeless thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ward) has provided many definitions for the word "ward", out of which I found a few that fits your description :

> **Ward** ( Archaic.) :
>   a. The act of guarding or protecting; guardianship.
>   b. The act of keeping watch or being a lookout.
>   c. The state of being under guard; custody.
>
> **Ward** :
>    A defensive movement or attitude, especially in fencing; a guard.

These are the closest definition I found for the word *"ward"*. You should explore a bit more in that link if you think none of the descriptions I've mentioned above fits your context.

Comment: And of course, it still appears with this meaning in the word 'wardrobe'. . .